# Is SSL required for Oauth?

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I have a webpp that is built on Django. I want to implement Facebook/Twitter login to increase convertion rates. The app is hosted on AWS EC2 and the domain is purchased under Namecheap.

Is it required for the webapp to have HTTPS in order to use OAuth for Facebook/Twitter login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is not required for Facebook or Twitter OAuth.
It's required for certain other bits of Facebook API functionality (page tabs and canvas apps), but not website login.

This doesn't seem to be explicitly documented anywhere, but I just tested both FB and Twitter login for one of my apps on a non-SSL page, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: it does not matter, ssl is only needed for canvas and page apps (apps on facebook.com)